# Как создать словарь генератором?

Tags: python

Как написать следующую логику создания словаря генератором словаря.

```
left_children =  [1, 3, 5, 7, -1, 9, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1] # левые потомки
right_children = [2, 4, 6, 8, -1, 10, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1] # правые потомки
```

```
result = {}
for idx, (right, left) in enumerate(zip(left_children, right_children)):
    if right != -1:
        result[right] = idx
        result[left] = idx
```

Я попытался написать, что-то подобное, но это неверно:

```
{right:idx, left:idx for idx, (right, left) in 
                                           enumerate(zip(left_children, right_children)) 
                                                                        if right != -1 }
```

Как исправить?

Comment: У вас что, не может быть дерева c узлами с одним потомком вроде `left_children =  [1, 2, -1, -1, -1] right_children = [3, -1, -1, 4, -1]` ?

Comment: Структура не предусматривает узлов с одним потомком. Это бинарное дерево.

Comment: В бинарном дереве общего вида могут быть узлы с одним потомком. Но если ваша задача не предусматривает такого ("правильное" дерево - full или proper), то хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
result = {
    k: idx
    for idx, (right, left) in enumerate(zip(left_children, right_children))
    if right != -1
    for k in (right, left)
}
```

Comment: супер. спасибо!